# Using XmlReader to Read XML

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5, xpath, xmlreader

I'm having some trouble using `XmlReader` to read an XML file.  I can open and close the file okay (I think), but when it comes to parsing out the information I need, I'm a bit lost.  Here is the bit of the file I need to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="Dictionary">
  <data>
    <Translations>
      <Translation UniversalAbbv="Enu" lang="en" localization="US" unicode="0">
        <Set>
          ...
        </Set>
        <Set>
          ...
        </Set>
        <Set>
          <CaseSensitive value="0" />
          <Enums translate="1">
            <Enum_Entry ENUM_H="STOPRUN_STOP" EnumID="0" EnumString="Stop" SetID="160" />
            <Enum_Entry ENUM_H="STOPRUN_RUN" EnumID="1" EnumString="Run" SetID="160" />
            <Enum_Entry ENUM_H="STOPRUN_HOLD " EnumID="2" EnumString="Hold" SetID="160" />
          </Enums>
          <IncludeFiles_cs name="CSFile" value="StopRun.cs" />
          <IncludeFiles_h name="Header" value="NULL" />
          <IncludeFiles_java name="Java" value="NULL" />
          <SetID value="160" />
          <SetName value="Stop Run" />
          <TwoSet ENUM_H="STOPRUN_ENUM_SET" />
        </Set>
        <Set>
          ...
        </Set>
   </Translation>
  </Translations>
  </data>
</database>
```

I need to find where `EnumID="0"` or `EnumID="1"` (or `"STOPRUN_STOP"` or `"STOPRUN_RUN"`) and respectively pull out the `"Stop"` or `"Run"` strings.  Here's what I have for code so far:

```
static class Dictionary
{
    static private XmlReader Reader = null;

    static public void Open()
    {
        XML_Generator.Dictionary.Reader = XmlReader.Create(XML_Generator.Program.DictionaryFilename);
    }

    static public void Close()
    {
        XML_Generator.Dictionary.Reader.Close();
    }

    static public void Read()
    {
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation(XML_Generator.Dictionary.Reader.ReadElementContentAsString()); // <-- This throw an error. :(
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's not much, but I'm a bit lost on where to go with this.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using XMLReader instead of LINQ or even XMLDocument?

Comment: I generally will read into a Dataset, and then index into it to look for the value(s) i'm interested in. Curious to see how others might do it.

Comment: @AlexMendez: I've never needed to parse an XML file before.  Is LINQ a .NET class?

Comment: @timmy: How is Dataset used?  Can you link to an example?

Comment: LINQ is a Language-Integrated Query and is part of the .net 3.5 and above. It allows you to query your xml in a similar maner as you would sql server. Here are some samples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397965.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at the [XpathNavigator](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333). The [syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) of it is really easy to use, much easier than doing it with the XMLReader

All you'd need to do to get the EnumID="1" item is `//Enums/Enum_Entry[@EnumID=1]`

Comment: `XPathNavigator` does seem much simpler to use.  I've since learned that I need to use `"STOPRUN_ENUM_SET"` to grab the `"Stop"` and '"Run"` attributes from the XML that I posted.  Is there a way to do that with `XPathNavigator`?

Comment: `STOPRUN_ENUM_SET`? that does not seem to make much sense based on your example. I guess you mean `STOPRUN_STOP`? `//Enum_Entry[@ENUM_H="STOPRUN_STOP"]`
anyway, if you don't want to code everything already, you can mess around with the queries at: <http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx> and see which gets selected.

Comment: Here's the expression I have so far, but it's not pulling anything from the XML file: `Translations/Translation/Set/TwoSet[@ENUM_H='STOPRUN_ENUM_SET']/../Enums/Enum_Entry[@EnumID < 2]`

Comment: `//Translations/Translation/Set/TwoSet[@ENUM_H='STOPRUN_ENUM_SET']` at least pulls the entire set... however, in your example xml you left out the data for the TwoSet item. Anyway just `//TwoSet` does the same. You don't have to start at the root node if you don't need anything from it

Comment: Okay, I think I got it figured out.  Thanks for all the help! `//Set/TwoSet[@ENUM_H='STOPRUN_ENUM_SET']/../Enums/Enum_Entry[@EnumID<2]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is example to read xml file using XML Reader

```
   int intCount = 0;
    XmlReaderSettings objSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    objSettings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
    objSettings.IgnoreComments = true;
    string booksFile = Server.MapPath("books.xml");
    using (XmlReader objReader = XmlReader.Create(booksFile, objSettings))
    {
        while (objReader.Read())
        {
            if (objReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && "Book" == objReader.LocalName)
            {
                 intCount++;
            }
            if (objReader.NodeType ==XmlNodeType.Text )
            {
                Response.Write("<BR />" + objReader.Value);
            }
        }
    }
    Response.Write(String.Format("<BR /><BR /><BR /><b> Total {0} books.</b>", intCount));
```